# Routing with codeigniter - ID not passed

Tags: php, codeigniter-2

I've recently picked up Codeigniter as a fun little side project, now I'm trying to make my routes to be as follows;

```
http://localhost/c/show/ID
```

should translate into

```
http://localhost/c/ID
```

I do it in routes in config like so;

```
$route['c/:any'] = "c/show/$1";
```

However, the ID is simply passed as plaintext, which means the ID passed to my show() function is $1, and not whatever ID is set to.

Am I going about this wrong? I've simply looked around in their documentation and even tried copy&replace to make sure it's not something that I typed wrong.

Now I fear I might have missunderstood something but I cannot phatom what that could be.

Really grateful for any and all help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

":any" should be in brackets, like this:

```
$route['c/(:any)'] = "c/show/$1";
```

Btw if ID is numeric, it's better to use:

```
$route['c/(:num)'] = "c/show/$1";
```